# FlaskForm not accepting field name 'process'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

When I put the name of the field to 'process', Flask fails to process my form.
Here is the example code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    process = StringField('My StringField')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'MySecret'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template_string(f'<div>{form.process.label}{form.process}</div>')
app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Above code give error as

```sh
/home/flask/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 208, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/flask/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 73, in __init__
    super().__init__(formdata=formdata, **kwargs)
  File "/home/flask/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.process(formdata, obj, data=data, **kwargs)
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

This works fine if I renamed the field from `process = StringField('My StringField')` to any other name, e.g. `myprocess`. Why is that? how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

form.process() is actually a reserved function in Flask-forms for when one has to define default values during initialization. You should use some other field name such as process_ for your form.

Comment: But in my input data, the key name is `process` if I put another field name then it won't accept the value of the `process` key. Any trick to ask the FlaskForm class to accept another key name other than field name?

Comment: I know the obvious answer to change the key name in input data.